# Get text box value in next page in Sitecore 7.2 with Web Form for Marketer

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.2

I created one Feedback form in Sitecore 7.2 by Web form for marketer(2.4) .
After submitting the form ,instead of displaying success message on same page I am redirecting user to "Thank-you" page. I want to display thank you message with "Email ID"  that used to fill the form.

How i can get last page value in sitecore.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good post by Mike Reynolds on Show Submitted Web Forms for Marketers Form Field Values on a Confirmation Page in Sitecore. http://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/06/14/show-submitted-web-forms-for-marketers-form-field-values-on-a-confirmation-page-in-sitecore/

Unfortunately you do not modified the Success Page pipeline but rather create a custom Save Action instead.